# Why is Checked attribute not working for radio button using PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code snippet:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>Fruits</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='fruit' value='Apple'    ($fruit=='Apple')?'checked':''> Apple
    <input type='radio' name='chamber' value='Banana' ($fruit=='Banana')?'checked':''> Banana</td>
    </tr>";
```

Value of `$fruit` is `Apple` but still the the radio button attribute is not being set to `checked`.

Comment: and why are you using radio button when they have a different name attribute? Just use checkbox

Comment: I assume that `name='chamber'` is just a typo?

Comment: @jeroen: good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the output of this you can see that the statement will not execute as you want because it's inside the `" "`. You need to break the `"` before and continue after the check like this:

```
echo "<tr>
 <td>Fruits</td>
 <td>
 <input type='radio' name='fruit' value='Apple'  " .  (($fruit=='Apple')?'checked="checked"':'') . "> Apple
 <input type='radio' name='chamber' value='Banana' " .(($fruit=='Banana')?'checked="checked"':'') . "> Banana</td>
</tr>";
```

And better to include all inside brackets `(...)` to not mess with something else.

Also it's better to have `checked="checked"` when you want to mark something as checked.

Answer (score 0):

In your example either you can add `?'checked':''` inside the `($fruit=='Apple')` or add one more bracket for all `ternary`.

**Example (it's better to use `<?php ?>` where you need):**

```
<tr>
<td>Fruits</td>
<td>
<input type='radio' name='fruit' value='Apple' <?=($fruit=='Apple' ? 'checked' : '')?>> Apple
<input type='radio' name='fruit' value='Banana' <?=($fruit=='Banana' ? 'checked' : '')?>> Banana</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest wasy if any problem is found:

```html
if($fruit=='Apple') $check="checked"; else $check="";
if($fruit=='Banana') $check="checked"; else $check="";
 
echo "<tr>
 <td>Fruits</td>
 <td>
 <input type='radio' name='fruit' value='Apple'  " .$check. "> Apple
 <input type='radio' name='chamber' value='Banana' " .$check. "> Banana</td>
</tr>";
```